# Do you need to defer .count() in pymongo and twisted?

Tags: python, twisted, pymongo

I am running twisted with pymongo. I know that when using pymongo .find() query you need to defer it when you iterate over the cursor.

Does the same apply to .count()? Do I need to defer it or is it non-stopping?

EDIT: if it has to be deferred, what would be the proper way of doing it?

Do I need to create a cursor first and then call count on it:

```
value_deferred = deferToThread(
                mongo_collection.find,
                mongo_query,
            )
value_deferred.count()
```

or is there any way to get the count right away?

If I do this:

```
def get_filtered_count():
    return db_collection.find(mongo_query).count()

value_to_get = deferToThread(get_filtered_count())
```

I get this error: exceptions.TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

EDIT 2: Is the use of yield here justified? I get errors when calling it otherwise.

```
@inlineCallbacks
def render_deferred(self, request):
  cursor = self.mongo.find()
  get_counter = yield deferToThread(cursor.count)
  page_size = 3
  number_of_pages = get_counter / page_size
  return final_value

def render_GET(self, request):
  ## some code
  deferred = self.render_deferred(request)

  deferred.addCallback(_send, request)
  deferred.addErrback(handle_failure, request)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you must defer is the actual call to `count`. The `find` method just creates a cursor and does no I/O, whereas calling `count` does. So you can call `find` on the main thread or the worker thread, depending on what's convenient.

When you call deferToThread, pass the function, don't call it:

```
value_to_get = deferToThread(get_filtered_count)
```

Or just:

```
cursor = collection.find(query)
deferred = deferToThread(cursor.count)
```

Comment: Thanks. In that case, do I need to first create a cursor in the deferToThread and then call a count on it? See my edit, please.

Comment: There's usually no harm in creating the cursor in the thread. The cursor can also be created in the main thread and passed in as a parameter in ``deferToThread``

Comment: Minor issue, it should be ``deferToThread(get_filtered_count)``

Comment: Thanks. My last question. I need to use it within another deferToThread. So when I do what you have in your answer I get an instance type and not int. When I try to do int(deferred) I get an error something like: "has no truncate ...". So when I do "deferred = yield deferToThread(cursor.count)", it gives me an int right away. Is this a bad practice to use yield like this???

Comment: You need to go back to basics and understand deferreds and yields in Twisted. But a few basic principles: don't deferToThread from another background thread, only deferToThread from the main thread. That's all that's needed to avoid blocking the Reactor, which is running on the main thread. "yield" is a way of pausing a coroutine on the main thread, please learn about "inline callbacks."

Comment: This count call is deferred in the main thread, so I guess it is fine. I don't really understand your comment about "yield pausing a coroutine", can you point me to some documentation on this? Thanks!